# Android add animation on finish() with onPause()

Tags: android, android-animation, onpause, activity-finish

When I try to add animation on onPause() method, The animation begin, and in the middle of the process the Animation disappear, too early.

This is my method:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_left_in, R.anim.trans_left_out);
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: try to use a handler, normally onpause stops animations itself

Comment: Are you using AnimatorSet or Animator or Animation object?

Answer (score 0):

[overridePendingTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) is meant to be called after `startActivity` or `finish` :

> Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or
>   finish() to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.

Using it elsewhere is not garanteed to work. Worse, the result may depend on the device / Android version.